# jump on sprite touch using box2d

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, box2d

I am new cocos2dx developer.I am using cocos2dx v3.7.1. now i want to jump sprite on touch the sprite.I refer many answer but i am confused.
                i implement below code in HelloWorld.cpp file

```
             Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
            {

              auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
                scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
                 //scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setGravity(Vec2(0,0.0));
                auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
                layer->SetPhysicsWorld( scene->getPhysicsWorld() );
                scene->addChild(layer);
                return scene;
            }

            // on "init" you need to initialize your instance
            bool HelloWorld::init()
            {
                //////////////////////////////
                // 1. super init first
                if ( !Layer::init() )
                {
                    return false;
                }
                auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
                auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
                touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);

                touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
                touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchEnded, this);
                touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchMoved, this);

                dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);

         sprite3 = Sprite::create("kartoon.png");
            sprite3->setPosition(Point(40,40));
            sprite3->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));            spritibody=PhysicsBody::createBox(sprite3->getContentSize(),PhysicsMaterial(0,1,0));
                sprite3->setPhysicsBody( spritibody );
                spritibody->setDynamic(true);
               this->addChild(sprite3,4);
   this->schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE(&HelloWorld::chek),0.01f);
            return true;
           }
 void HelloWorld::chek()
   {

                if (sprite3->getPosition().y>109) {
                    yvel-=0.1;
                }
                else{

                    if(yvel!=6)
                    {
                        xvel=0;
                        yvel=0;
                    }
                }
                sprite3->setPosition(Vec2(sprite3->getPosition().x+xvel,sprite3->getPosition().y+yvel));

            }
    bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
    {
        CCLOG("onTouchBegan x = %f, y = %f", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
        auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
        Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
        if(sprite3->boundingBox().containsPoint(locationInNode))
        {

            // spritibody->setVelocity(Vec2(2, 0));
         spritibody->applyImpulse(Vec2(0,40));
            sprite3->setPhysicsBody(spritibody);
           spritibody->setGravityEnable(true);
            }
      return true;

    }
```

In this when i tap on sprite, its jump continous and after some type sprite3 go out off screen.But i want to only jump one time when i tap on sprite3.
plese help me.

Comment: this may be the problem: sprite3->setPosition(Vec2(sprite3->getPosition().x+xvel,sprite3->getPosition().y+yvel));

when is this called. Is it called on each frame? Because if it is, it will always set the Y position of the sprite and yvel doesn't decrease with too much.

Comment: ok thank you.I try to remove that line